# Cleaning stacks in target account by pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-pipelines-datalake-infrastructure) and i have problem with cleaning the infra in target account. The flow detail
1 : `developer` -commit-> `github` -> `DeplopmentAccount:Pipeline` pull the code then deploy the `Aws Cloudformation stack` to `TargetAccount:cloudformation` .
Test Cdk Pipeline will deploy the stack in TestAccount which is the good thing

2.But when we want to clean up with `cdk destroy --all`, it only destroys the `Test CDK Pipeline` , the stacks in `Test Account` still remains.
So my question is how do we destroy all stacks ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't abandon your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is mentioned in the tutorial you linked:

> Clean up
>
> Delete stacks using the command cdk destroy --all. When you see the following text, enter y, and press enter/return.

```
ProdDataLakeCDKBlogInfrastructurePipeline,
DevDataLakeCDKBlogInfrastructurePipeline (y/n)?
```

> **Note: This operation deletes stacks only in central deployment account**
>
> To delete stacks in development account, log onto Dev account, go to AWS CloudFormation console and delete the following stacks:
>
> - Dev-DevDataLakeCDKBlogInfrastructureVpc
> - Dev-DevDataLakeCDKBlogInfrastructureS3BucketZones
> - Dev-DevDataLakeCDKBlogInfrastructureIam
>
> Note:
> Deletion of Dev-DevDataLakeCDKBlogInfrastructureS3BucketZones will delete the S3 buckets (raw, conformed, and purpose-built). This
> behavior can be changed by modifying the retention policy in s3_bucket_zones_stack.py
>
> To delete stacks in test account, log onto ~~Dev~~ Test account, go to AWS CloudFormation console and delete the following stacks:
>
> - Test-TestDataLakeCDKBlogInfrastructureVpc
> - Test-TestDataLakeCDKBlogInfrastructureS3BucketZones
> - Test-TestDataLakeCDKBlogInfrastructureIam
>
> Note:
> The S3 buckets (raw, conformed, and purpose-built) have retention policies attached and must be removed manually when they are
> no longer needed.
>
> To delete stacks in prod account, log onto ~~Dev~~ Prod account, go to AWS CloudFormation console and delete the following stacks:
>
> - Prod-ProdDataLakeCDKBlogInfrastructureVpc
> - Prod-ProdDataLakeCDKBlogInfrastructureS3BucketZones
> - Prod-ProdDataLakeCDKBlogInfrastructureIam
>
> Note:
> The S3 buckets (raw, conformed, and purpose-built) have retention policies attached and must be removed manually when they are
> no longer needed.

It erroneously says that you have to log into the Dev account for Test and Prod, I have corrected it in the quote.

Alternatively, you can call `cdk destroy --all` with the `--profile` flag and set it to the dev/test/prod AWS credentials profile.

Comment: No, the fact is to delete stacks in prod account , i have to log in to `prod` account -> delete stack . In test stack => i have to login to test account , and login dev account to delete stacks in dev. Which is not good because in reality i do not have enough permission to login and delete stacks in `test` and `prod` . Maybe the original readme is wrong.

Comment: Yes, the readme says you have to log in to the account to delete the stack - it is correct in that regard. Are you saying you have enough permissions to create a stack, but not to delete a stack?